# How to get grouped expression and global flag working at the same time in Javascript regular expressions?

Tags: javascript, regex

Based on [this MDN example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match#Example:_Using_match),
I expected the following `String.prototype.match()` with a regular expression:

```
var contents = '            <i class="sprite-lib-name--image-name"></i>';
var regex = /\<i\s[^\>]*class\=[\"\']sprite-([\w-]+)--([\w-]+)[\"\'][^\>]*\>/gim ;
contents.match(regex);
```

... to yield this expected output:

```
["<i class=\"sprite-lib-name--image-name\">", "lib-name", "image-name"]
```

... however I got this actual output:

```
["<i class="sprite-lib-name--image-name">"]
```

Not sure why the `([\w-]+)` group expression does not work.

However, when I remove the global match flag (`g`),
the match works as expected.

```
var contents = '            <i class="sprite-lib-name--image-name"></i>';
var regex = /\<i\s[^\>]*class\=[\"\']sprite-([\w-]+)--([\w-]+)[\"\'][^\>]*\>/im ;
contents.match(regex);
//Output: ["<i class=\"sprite-lib-name--image-name\">", "lib-name", "image-name"]
```

The trouble is that I need both group expression matching and global matching at the same time.
How can I accomplish this?

```
var contents = '            <i class="sprite-lib-name--image-name"></i> <i class="sprite-lib-name--another-image"></i>';
var regex = /\<i\s[^\>]*class\=[\"\']sprite-([\w-]+)--([\w-]+)[\"\'][^\>]*\>/im ;
contents.match(regex);
//Output: ["<i class=\"sprite-lib-name--image-name\">", "lib-name", "image-name"]
//Second output missing
```

Comment: try `regex.exec(contents)`

Comment: In theory they should be the same, no? (scurries off to the console to try it out)

Comment: @AvinashRaj Hmm, turns out it has a slightly different behaviour - the global option does not stop the group expression from being captured. However, the second instance gets missed... So still no dice.

Answer (score 1):

using the `g` flag with `match` will only match whole matches - not sub matches. Typically you would use exec in a while loop to solve this problem. Not as concise, but should work.

```
var match, matches = [];
while (match = regex.exec(contents) ) {
    matches.push(match[1], match[2]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I assume that this means that the regex retains the position/ index of the previous match automatically?

Comment: Results in an infiinite loop - looks like Regexp.lastIndex is only used when the global flag is present

Comment: - [lastIndex on global regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex)
- [sticky flag in ES6 regexes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/sticky)